# How to save dynamic ListBox items to a text file WP8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I have a ListBox that on run is empty, but the items (Buttons ) are added dynamically. I have a text file in my Solution favorites.txt and I need that ListBox.Items name to be save for future show.
In XAML I have 2 Buttons that are placed in different ListBoxes in Line:

```
<ListBox x:Name="mainlist" >
    <Button x:Name="but1" / >     
</ListBox>
<ListBox x:Name="favlist" >                         
    <Button x:Name="fav1" Click="Button_Click_2" Tag="but1" />
</ListBox>
```

Next in .cs I search for but1 by fav1.Tag and add it to Favorites List Box :

```
 private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

            var button = (Button)sender;
            button.Opacity = 0;
            button.Click -= Button_Click_2;
            object item = mainlist.FindName(button.Tag.ToString());     
                if (item is Button)
                {

                    Button findedBut = (Button)item;
                    Button newbut = new Button();
                    newbut.Name = findedBut.Name;
                    //add this button to other ListBox called Favorites that is empty
                    Favorites.Items.Add(newbut);
                }

            }
```

And I want to save Favorite Items for future launching because if I close applications the ListBox Favorites is empty again.
Something Like a function:

```
void updateFavs()
{
// this is not working ((
 using (FileStream S = File.Open((new Uri(@"favorites.txt", UriKind.Relative)), FileMode.Open))
                    {
                        using (StreamWriter st = new StreamWriter(S))
                         {
                            foreach (var aa in Favorites.Items)
                                st.WriteLine(aa.ToString());
                         }
                    }
}
```

and call this functions every time before `Application.Current.Terminate();`
Or maybe there is other ways that I don't know... maybe Isolated Storage? Like here:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj681698%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have to use the Isolated Storage:

```
\\Create file and save data
  using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Create, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
            {
                using (StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine(1);
                    writer.WriteLine("Hello");
                }
            }

\\To read from the file
using (IsolatedStorageFileStream stream = new IsolatedStorageFileStream("file.txt", FileMode.Open, IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication()))
{
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        int number = Convert.ToInt32(reader.ReadLine());
        string text = reader.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: that helped me but I have one more question:
How to handle if the file is not found? Because I want first to read from file On  `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` and on Exit to update the file?

Comment: You can for example use try and catch